# Rails callbacks behaving differently on different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have two Rails environments. One development environment running Postgres and Rails 5.0.6 and an almost identical environment on Heroku.

I have an `Administrator` class, which generates a username for an `Administrator` on a `before_save` callback based on the user's `forename` and `surname` fields.

```
class Administrator < ApplicationRecord

  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  validates :forename, presence: true
  validates :surname, presence: true

  before_save :generate_username

  def generate_username
    return if username.present?
    proposed = "#{forename}#{surname}".downcase
    existing_count = Administrator.where("username ILIKE ?", "#{proposed}%").size
    self.username = existing_count.zero? ? proposed : "#{proposed}#{existing_count}"
  end
end
```

After the user is validated, a username is generated in the form `FORENAMESURNAMEX` where X is an incrementing number (or nothing).

Here's the commands I run in the Rails console on my development machine.

```
irb(main):012:0> Administrator.create(email: 'edward@test.net', forename: 'Edward', surname: 'Scissorhands')
D, [2017-10-13T10:00:18.985765 #280] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-10-13T10:00:18.987554 #280] DEBUG -- :   Administrator Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "administrators" WHERE "administrators"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "edward@test.net"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-13T10:00:18.988923 #280] DEBUG -- :   Administrator Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "administrators" WHERE "administrators"."username" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-13T10:00:18.990155 #280] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "administrators" WHERE (username ILIKE 'edwardscissorhands%')
D, [2017-10-13T10:00:18.992000 #280] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "administrators" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at", "username", "forename", "surname") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "edward@test.net"], ["created_at", "2017-10-13 10:00:18.990421"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-13 10:00:18.990421"], ["username", "edwardscissorhands"], ["forename", "Edward"], ["surname", "Scissorhands"]]
D, [2017-10-13T10:00:18.995845 #280] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Administrator id: 10, email: "edward@test.net", created_at: "2017-10-13 10:00:18", updated_at: "2017-10-13 10:00:18", role: nil, otp_public_key: nil, username: "edwardscissorhands", forename: "Edward", surname: "Scissorhands">
```

As you can see, the callback is executed and the user's username is generated and persisted to the database as expected.

However, when I run the same code on a our test environment running on Heroku (and Heroku Postgres), this is what happens:

```
irb(main):005:0> Administrator.create!(email: 'edward@test.net', forename: 'Edward', surname: 'Scissorhands')
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
  Administrator Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "administrators" WHERE "administrators"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "edward@test.net"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Administrator Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "administrators" WHERE "administrators"."username" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Username has already been taken
```

(I'm using `create!` here instead of `create` to show the validation errors that do not occur in development.)

I don't see why the behaviour should differ between environments. Both are running identical versions of Rails (5.0.6) and are running identical codebases.

Comment: Is this a typo or present in your code? `Administrator.where("username ILIKE ?", "#{proposed}%").size` `ILIKE` should be `LIKE`.

Comment: ILIKE is LIKE but case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before_save is called after validation, hence the error.

Try before_validation instead.

For reference here's the order callbacks are called when creating an object:

- before_validation
- after_validation
- before_save
- around_save
- before_create
- around_create
- after_create
- after_save
- after_commit/after_rollback

Comment: Yep this was right. It turned out we had dirty test data that was causing the validation to fail because we'd chosen the wrong callback for our situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your code is flawed. This is a legitimate bug; you need to redesign how username generation words.

For example, suppose there is one user in your system called: `edwardscissorhands1`. There is no `edwardscissorhands`, and no `edwardscissorhands2/3/4` etc.

The line: `Administrator.where("username ILIKE ?", "edwardscissorhands%").size` returns `1`, and then your logic tries to create a new user that already exists.

... I cannot say for sure what has happened on your production server without seeing the actual data, but I bet it's something like this. It could be slightly more convoluted, e.g. the users: `tom`, `tom3` and `tomlord` exist; therefore your logic tries to create a second `tom3` user.

For example, this might have happened if you generated some `edwardscissorhards` users, then **deleted** one or more of them.

As an **example**, here's one way you could redesign the logic:

```
def generate_username
  return if username.present?
  proposed = "#{forename}#{surname}".downcase
  return proposed unless Administrator.exists?("username ILIKE ?", proposed)

  counter = 1
  while(Administrator.exists?("username ILIKE ?", "#{proposed}#{counter}"))
    counter += 1
  end

  "#{proposed}#{counter}"
end
```

This could probably be improved performance-wise, although the multiple database queries here are unlikely to be a major issue in the real application (assuming you don't get *lots* of administrators with the same name!).